# Is "months to come" correct usage?

Tags: meaning

While I was watching a video on YouTube, I heard this sentence:

> Well, John, we'll see how it plays out and months to come.

The *and months to come* part sounds a little weird to me. Is it a correct usage? Does it mean *in the next few months*?

Answer (score 2):

Usually this is phrased as "...in the months to come," which means, in the next few months.

"...and months to come" sounds a bit weird to me, too. If the person said this in the video, and there was a caption, perhaps the caption was incorrect. Or perhaps the speaker simply misspoke.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is the video with the time spot: https://youtu.be/4X81eIE7zic?t=147 Could you help me check if what I heard is correct?